React Native build error could not get unknown property 'url'
I am trying to use Cognex library for scanning barcodes. Npm installed the library. In the instructions it is asked to open the app build.gradle located in yourRNApp/android/app.  Above the dependencies, replace the previously added repositories with this:
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs '../../node_modules/cmbsdk-react-native/android/cmbsdk-android-binary/cmbsdklib-release/', '../../node_modules/cmbsdk-react-native/android/cmbsdk-crossplatform-android-binary/'
    }
}

I did exactly that and recieved the error:
Could not get unknown property 'url' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultFlatDirArtifactRepository.

Gradle version in the project is 6.7, JVM - 11.0.16.1.
any insight would be appreciated
